# Can run server in Docker but can't acces to it (windows DockerTollbox)

Tags: python, django, docker, server

I started a Docker server and Kinetic says that my container is runnig. Everything seems okay but i can't access the server via http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Though i can access the server and see my django project if i run server without docker

I have not even a idea on what to do

Here's Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine
MAINTAINER Sabir Javadov

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

WORKDIR /Test
COPY ./Test /Test

RUN adduser -D Sabir
USER Sabir
```

Here's docker-compose

```
version: "3"

services:
  test:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./Test:/Test
    command: sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Comment: In Docker Toolbox you need the IP address reported by `docker-machine ip`, often 192.168.99.100.

Comment: Can you please give me a detailed instruction on where should I put this IP address?
i'm extemely new to coding and docker

Comment: Instead of 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Docker on windows runs on a Virtual Machine. If you are not using "Docker for Windows" but "Docker Toolbox" instead, you need to access your containers using the VM's IP.

You can find this by opening the "Docker Toolbox" terminal. Check the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/#step-3-verify-your-installation).

Comment: all this Hello-World staff works perfectly
and i installed NDIS5 driver
my project is in Users/User/Dev/Sabir so Toolbox must have acces to it by default isn't it?

Comment: @Sabir this is not related to a driver. With `Docker toolbox` you have to access the containers using the VM IP not `localhost`